# How to find the length of a line in a tetrahedron

Tags: vectors

I apologize the poor image quality and that I don't know how to rotate the image, please see image below.

[An image showing the geometric arrangement of the points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuZxw.jpg)

In this tetrahedron, angle α and β are known and the following are true:
AC=BC;
AO=BO;
OC is perpendicular to plane ABC

As a result, the following are true:
angles: CAB=CBA=(180-α)/2; OAB=OBA=(180-β)/2

The question is: what is the length of OC? 
(In terms of other lengths and angles)

Comment: There's still not enough information. What about the angle between planes $OAB$ and $CAB?$

Comment: My question was the angle between the **planes** $OAB$ and $CAB.$ Or else you could change $OC$ just by changing this angle.

Comment: Sorry for misinterpreting your question, I forgot to add some conditions, this may take some time modifying

Comment: Also, is it permitted to repost this question since I made so many mistake while asking?

Comment: It's fine. Take your time.

Comment: I fixed my solution to account for your additional perpendicularity condition.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP uploaded a near-duplicate question to account for all the errors made in posting this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $2k$ be the length of $AB$. We can position the tetrahedron so that $A$ and $B$ lie at $(0,0,k)$ and $(0,0,-k)$, respectively. Note that $C$ lies on the origin-centered circle on the $xy$-plane of radius $r_C = k\cdot\cot(\alpha/2)$, and $O$ lies on the origin-centered circle on the $xy$-plane of radius $r_O = k\cdot\cot(\beta/2)$. We may orient the tetrahedron so that $C$ lies on the positive $x$-axis; i.e., $C = (r_C, 0, 0)$. Then $O = (r_C, a, 0)$ for some $a$, and we wish to determine $|a|$. The Pythagorean Theorem tells us that $r_C^2 + a^2 = r_O^2$, which yields the final answer of $\frac{|AB|}{2}\sqrt{\cot(\beta/2)^2 - \cot(\alpha/2)^2}$.

Comment: thank you for your very helpful answer and I wish you a great day.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x$ be the length of $OA = OB$ and $y$ the length of $CA = CB.$

Using trigonometry, we have that the height perpendicular to $AB$ on $\Delta OAB$ is $x\cos(\frac{\beta}{2}),$ and that perpendicular to $AB$ on $\Delta CAB$ is $y\cos(\frac{\alpha}{2}).$

Now we use Pythagoras on right triangle $\Delta OCP,$ where $P$ is the midpoint of $AB.$ We find that $$\boxed{OC = \sqrt{x^{2}\cos^{2}(\frac{\beta}{2}) - y^{2}\cos^{2}(\frac{\alpha}{2})}}$$