# Find a length in a tetrahedron (Restated)

Tags: vectors

*For those of you who have seen me post this question, and especially if you have answered it, I apologize gravely for not stating all conditions clearly the first time around, I have flagged the original post for deletion.

The question involves a irregular tetrahedron, which appears as in the following image. I apologize for the poor quality and inconvenient rotation.

[An image showing the geometric arrangement of points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Td1z.jpg)

In this tetrahedron, the following variables are known:

α = angle ACB;

β = angle AOB;

AB, AO and BO

...and the following are true:

AC=BC;

AO=BO;

OC is perpendicular to plane ABC

The question is: what is the length of OC in terms of the known variables?

Comment: Just because you have restated your question does not mean that this fits the acceptable form of a question on Math.SE. I would recommend a couple things: First, use MathJax to format your mathematics. A guide can be found [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Second, post the image within the post itself, not a link. This makes the post easier to read and a bit more professional.

Comment: I would also use an image drawing software (heck, you could use MS Paint if you want) to redraw the image in a higher quality, rotated in a more understandable direction (although this is not necessary per-se)

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I would pay attention to these the next time around.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen: Users with low reputation cannot post inline images. And there's no "acceptability" requirement to post with MathJax (has been the meta consensus each time I've seen it discussed).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Really? I didn't know about the inline image thing... I'll make note of that (I didn't ask a question until about 1000 rep, so I never ran into that problem). As for MathJax, I suppose you are right here. I didn't mean "acceptable" in the sense that the question should be deleted; I simply meant that you would be more likely to get interest in a question if  it looks neater and more professional. Perhaps "acceptable" was not the right word there.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP's question was answered on his/her original post. This post is a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help of dshin, this question has been resolved

@MISC {1616105,
    TITLE = {How to find the length of a line in a tetrahedron},
    AUTHOR = {dshin (https://math.stackexchange.com/users/16006/dshin)},
    HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
    NOTE = {URL:https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1616105 (version: 2016-01-17)},
    EPRINT = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1616105},
    URL = {https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1616105}
}

Comment: What? So you got an answer on your original question? This is one reason duplicating posts is a very bad idea... it's unclear what progress has been made.

Comment: This is one of my first posts after quitting an unfortunate other forum, so this kind of things may happen, is there anyway to fix this that you know?

Comment: That's kind of a tough question, and is more one that belongs on Meta... If you are asking for what I would do, I would have simply edited the original post you made until it said what you wanted it to. If someone answered the question before you correct I would politely ask the person to either remove or edit the question as seems appropriate. Now, this isn't very kind to the person who answered, which is a big reason to make sure you get the question right the first time. However, any reasonable user will likely understand if you carefully explain, especially since you are new

Comment: If the answerer to your original question accommodated your edits sufficiently as to actually resolve the question you had in mind, then it's probably best just to keep the question and just edit it into shape. If the original question is deleted as you asked (unlikely to happen since you've accepted an answer), how is this answer (which would just be a link to a "question deleted" screen) going to be of any use?

Comment: You should definitely vote to close this question now though... it is very redundant. It takes 5 people with a rep over 3000 voting to close (unless someone has a gold badge in "vectors" questions, in which it only takes one I believe). Your answer above should also be made a comment, not an answer, and I would remove everything after the "@" sign... just explain that the question was answered on your original post and perhaps provide a single link to the original question.

Comment: How do I vote to close?

Comment: I think you can just delete it, right? There aren't any upvotes on either the question or the answer.

Comment: No, not enough reputation, I can only flag the question to be deleted

Comment: That's odd. [This help topic](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-questions) doesn't mention any rep requirement for deleting your own question, while [there is supposed to be a requirement for flagging](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).